# Dockerfile - Angular2

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN apt-get -y install npm
RUN apt install nodejs-legacy
RUN npm cache clean
RUN npm install -g angular-cli --force
RUN npm install -g watchman --force

ENV HOME=/home/app
WORKDIR $HOME
RUN ng new angular2
WORKDIR /home/app/angular2

EXPOSE 10000

CMD sudo ng serve --port 10000
```

Hello, I have this docker file...

```
docker build -t angular2 .
docker run -d angular2
```

Is it right? http://192.168.99.100:10000

I doesn't work. Why?

Comment: What does "It doesn't work" mean?

Comment: `docker run -d -p 10000:10000 angular2` ?

Comment: docker run -d -p 10000:10000 angular2. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Michalis What they meant was "It doesn't work" is meaningless without context. Please include what you expect to see and what you are actually seeing.

Comment: I expect to open the angular2 app to my browser. Now the server dosn't respond anything to this port.

Comment: Check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42270521/1099972