# Running Angular2 application in Docker

Tags: angular, docker, angular-cli

I'm trying to run my ng2 app in docker. I have the Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update

#Install curl & git
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl
RUN apt-get install -yqq git


#Download and install nodejs-6
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
RUN bash nodesource_setup.sh
RUN apt-get install -yqq nodejs
RUN apt-get install -yqq build-essential
RUN npm install -g angular-cli


#Clone the project
RUN git clone https://github.com/moravianlibrary/RecordManager2.git

WORKDIR /RecordManager2

#Checkout webapp_jobs_branch
RUN git checkout webapp_jobs_branch


#Go to the gui directory
WORKDIR /RecordManager2/cz.mzk.recordmanager.webapp.gui/gui

EXPOSE 4200

RUN npm install

CMD ["ng", "serve"]
```

building and running finish without errors:

```
docker build -t rm-gui .
docker run --name gui -dp 4200:4200 rm-gui
```

After running the app I can see that app is really running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
caa4f1f820d6        rm-gui              "ng serve"          23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes       0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp   gui
```

but when I open the page `http://localhost:4200/` I see an error `This site can’t be reached` . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: instead of using `localhost`, try with docker machine's IP. https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ip/

Answer (score 1):

in your `package.json` file set the following `start` command

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -H 0.0.0.0",
    .....
  },
```

in your `Dockerfile` replace the last line with

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: did not work the container started restarting itself every few seconds or so.